# mapping induces a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> let $E$ be a finite set with $|E|=n$ elements.
>   $\mathcal{E}=\{(A,B)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^{2} \mid A\cup B=E \}$
>
> I would like to show that construction of my function $f$  induces a bijection $\mathcal{T}$
>
> Let for every $(A,B)$ the function $f_{(A,B)}: E \to \{0,1,2\}$ be defined via : 
>     $$f(x)= 
>     \begin{cases}
>        0 &  \mbox{ if } \quad x\in A\setminus B \\
> & \\
>        1 & \mbox{ if } \quad x\in  A\cap B \\
> & \\
>        2 & \mbox{ if } \quad x\in  B\setminus A
>    \end{cases}
>  $$
>   This construction induces a bijection between $\mathcal{E}$ and $\{0,1,2\}^E$ via :
>   $$\begin{array}{ccccc}
>  \mathcal{T} & : & \mathcal{E} & \to & \{0,1,2\}^E \\
>  & & (A,B) & \mapsto & f_{(A,B)} \\
> \end{array}$$

My thoughts:

let's prove that  that $(A,B)\to f_{(A,B)}$ is an actual bijection.
so we have to check that $\mathcal{T}$ is :

- The function $\mathcal{T}$ is injective :
  $$\forall (A,B),(A',B')\in \mathcal{E},\;\;T((A,B))=T((A',B'))\Rightarrow (A,B)=(A',B')$$
- The function $\mathcal{T}$ is Surjective 
  $$\forall f_{(A,B)} \in \{0,1,2\}^E ,\,\exists (A,B)\in \mathcal{E},\;\;T((A,B))=f_{(A,B)}$$

indeed,

let  $(A,B),(A',B')\in \mathcal{E},\;\mbox{ such that } \;T((A,B))=T((A',B'))$ and show that $(A,B)=(A',B')$ 
note that 
$$(A,B)=(A',B')\iff \begin{cases} A\subset A' &\mbox{and } A'\subset A\\ 
B\subset B' &\mbox{and } B'\subset B \end{cases} $$
$A\subset A' \quad \iff  \quad x\in A \implies x\in A'$

$$x\in A \iff x\in A\setminus B \mbox{ or } x\in A\cap B$$
\begin{align*}
x\in A & \iff f_{(A,B)}(x)=0 \mbox{ or } f_{(A,B)}(x)=1 \\
& \iff f_{(A',B')}(x)=0 \mbox{ or } f_{(A',B')}(x)=1 ( \mbox{ since }f_{(A,B)}=f_{(A',B')}  ) \\
& \iff x\in A'\setminus B' \mbox{ or } x\in A'\cap B' \\
& \iff x\in A' \\
\end{align*}
$A=A'$
we have also $B=B'$  by analogy .

Then $\mathcal{T}$ is injective

- Is my proof correct until now

Comment: In the definition of $f$, did you mean $A\cap B$? As written, $f$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You might attempt case-analysis. If $(A,B)\neq(A',B')$, what happens if $A\cap B\neq A'\cap B'$? In this case can you identify some $x\in E$ on which $f_{(A,B)}(x)\neq f_{(A',B')}(x)$?

Otherwise, $A\cap B= A'\cap B'$. In this case there is some $x\in A\setminus B$ s.t. $x\in B'\setminus A'$ or vice versa (why?). What happens to $f_{(A,B)}(x)$ and $f_{(A',B')}(x)$?