# Find $A$ and $B$ Under certain conditions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> let $E$ be a finite set with $|E|=n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $$
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  f_{(A,B)}:& & E & \longrightarrow & \{0,1,2\} \\
>  & & x & \mapsto & f_{(A,B)}(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &  \mbox{ if } \quad x\in A\setminus B \\ & \\  1 & \mbox{ if } \quad x\in  A\cap B \\
> & \\ 2 & \mbox{ if } \quad x\in  B\setminus A \end{cases}\\
> \end{array}$$
>   Find $A$ and $B$ such that :
>   \begin{cases}
>  A,B \subset E,\;  A\cup B=E, \mbox{ and } |E|=n &\\
>  &\\
>  x\in A\setminus B\Leftrightarrow f(x)=0, &\\
>  &\\
>  x\in A\cap B\Leftrightarrow f(x)=1 &\\
>  &\\
>  x\in B\setminus A\Leftrightarrow f(x)=2\ &\\
>  \end{cases}

My Thoughts:

we have: $f^{-1}(0)=A \setminus B$, $f^{-1}(1)=A\cap B$, $f^{-1}(2) = B\setminus A$.
then we can pick up $A$ and $B$ as following:

$$A = f^{-1}(0) \cup f^{-1}(1) \mbox{ and } B = f^{-1}(2) \cup f^{-1}(1)$$

- Is my proof correct

Comment: Can you add any more details - is $E$ a subset of another set, like the reals, or is $f_{(A, B)}$ defined in any more detail? Because with the information given, there doesn't seem to be anything to find, as there seem to be trivial solutions - $A$ and $B$ are fully defined by the function.

Comment: i need to find A and B under that conditions to help me show surjection in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606580/mapping-induces-a-bijection

Comment: I think everything makes more sense if you define $f$ simply as an arbitrary function $E \to \{0,1,2\}$ and then wish to find $A,B \subseteq E$ that meet the conditions you originally lay out.

Comment: i defined like that due to my last question

Answer (score 1):

If $i=0,1,2,$ then $f^{-1}(i)=\{x\in E: f(x)=i\}$ is a set by using Axiom Schema of Separation. Also $f^{-1}(i)\subset E$, so we can define $A=f^{-1}(0)\cup f^{-1}(1)$ and $A$ is a set by using Axiom of Pairing,and subset of $E$. Simularly $B=f^{-1}(1)\cup f^{-1}(2)$ is a subset of $E$. So we confirmed that the exsistence of $A$ and $B$, as subsets of $E$.

Now we must show that; i) $A\cup B=E$, ii) $x\in A\setminus B \iff f(x)=0$, iii) $x\in A\cap B \iff f(x)=1$, iv) $x\in B\setminus A \iff f(x)=2$.

i) $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A \lor  x\in B$$\iff x\in f^{-1}(0)\lor x\in f^{-1}(1)\lor x\in f^{-1}(2) \iff x\in E$

ii) $x\in A\setminus B \iff x\in A, x\notin B\iff x\in f^{-1}(0)\iff f(x)=0$.   [use definetion $A$, $B$ and i) for the second $\iff$],

iii) $x\in A\cap B \iff x\in A, x\in B \iff x\in f^{-1}(0)\lor f^{-1}(1), x\in f^{-1}(1)\lor f^{-1}(2)\iff x\in  f^{-1}(1)\iff f(x)=1$. [For the third $\iff $, note that, $f^{-1}(i)\cap f^{-1}(j)=\emptyset$, for all $i\neq j$]

iv) Simularly ii)